# Comparaciones de fechas en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta entre un rango de fechas, y cuando uso el >= a la fecha de hoy (26/11/2018) si que me muestra, en cambio si uso solo el = a la fecha de hoy no me muestra nada, cuando no es lógico porque no hay ningún dato con fecha posterior.
Dejo el código:

```
SELECT
    substring(maquina_id,1,5), 
    count(distinct [rep].[id])
  FROM [matLot]
  LEFT JOIN [rep] on [matLot].[lot] = [rep].[id]
  where [fechaEntrada] >= cast('26/11/2018' AS datetime)
  group by substring([maquina_id],1,5)
  order by substring([maquina_id],1,5)
```

Comment: En un campo datetime igual implica mismo día y misma hora, tendrías que comparar sólo los valores de fecha (año-mes-día).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si comparas campos con el tipo datetime estás comparando el día y la hora, para comparar sólo por fecha comparas el campo datetime como date. Dejo un ejemplo.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  fecha DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO test (id, fecha) VALUES (1, '2018-11-26 01:00:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, fecha) VALUES (1, '2018-11-26 03:00:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, fecha) VALUES (1, '2018-11-27 01:00:00');
```

---

Comparando campos con `datetime` >= obtendremos todos los registros con fecha y hora mayor o igual al inicio del día de comparación, en este ejemplo '2018-11-26 00:00:00'.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE fecha >= CAST('2018-11-26' AS datetime)
;

| id  | fecha               |
| --- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 2018-11-26 01:00:00 |
| 1   | 2018-11-26 03:00:00 |
| 1   | 2018-11-27 01:00:00 |
```

---

Para obtener todos los registros de un día comparamos los datos como `date`.

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE CAST(fecha AS date) = CAST('2018-11-26' AS date)
;

| id  | fecha               |
| --- | ------------------- |
| 1   | 2018-11-26 01:00:00 |
| 1   | 2018-11-26 03:00:00 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Funciona para mi, en mi caso solo queria validar si la columna fecha trae algun valor inferior a una fecha estipulada, entonces use esto apoyando en tu respuesta, gracias... ```SELECT ....... CASE WHEN fecha <= CAST ('2000-01-01' AS datetime) THEN NULL ELSE fecha END AS 'Nombre de la columna'``` y me funciona excelente, en mi caso todas las fechas inferiores a 200-01-01 me las puso NULL en la consulta.